# How to use the same domain for multiple server DNSes in CPanel?

Tags: nameserver, cpanel

I'm wondering how can I use the same domain to setup 3 cPanel server DNSes, instead of having a dedicated domain for each server.

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

Server A:

Hostname: **a**.mydomain.com

Name Server 1: **ns1**.mydomain.com

Name Server 2: **ns2**.mydomain.com

Server B:

Hostname: **b**.mydomain.com

Name Server 1: **ns3**.mydomain.com

Name Server 2: **ns4**.mydomain.com

Server C:

Hostname: **c**.mydomain.com

Name Server 1: **ns5**.mydomain.com

Name Server 2: **ns6**.mydomain.com

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't ns1 and ns2 be authoritative for all three subdomains? Is there a reason you want 6 DNS servers for 3 total subdomains?

Comment: I think the op has misunderstood the distincting between a DNS zone and a nameserver

Answer (score 2):

Ok, what you've got there seems very odd. You setup should look something like this:

Hostname Setup:

```
Hostname: mydomain.com
Name Server 1: ns1.mydomain.com
Name Server 2: ns2.mydomain.com
Name Server 3: ns3.mydomain.com
Name Server 4: ns4.mydomain.com
Name Server 5: ns5.mydomain.com
Name Server 6: ns6.mydomain.com
```

I assume you are using a commerical DNS hosting provider? Or do you actually have 6 DNS servers? I'm assuming hosting because if you've got the know-how to synchronise 6 DNS servers then this would be a no-brainer for you.

So, log into your DNS hosting provider, and then create `a` records for your subdomains inside your zone for `mydomain.com`, such as

- `a` - `x.x.x.x`
- `b` - `y.y.y.y`
- `c` - `z.z.z.z`

(where x/y/z are the IP addresses of your actual servers).

Answer (score 0):

All three would have the same pair of nameservers. Just point each individual hostname at the addresses homed at the appropriate server.