# How to use the same domain for multiple server DNSes?

Tags: nameserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use the same domain for multiple server DNSes?](https://serverfault.com/questions/157485/how-to-use-the-same-domain-for-multiple-server-dnses)

Hello,

I'm wondering how can I use the same domain to setup 3 cPanel server DNSes, instead of having a dedicated domain for each server.

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

Server A:

Hostname: **a**.mydomain.com
Name Server 1: **ns1**.mydomain.com
Name Server 2: **ns2**.mydomain.com

Server B:

Hostname: **b**.mydomain.com
Name Server 1: **ns3**.mydomain.com
Name Server 2: **ns4**.mydomain.com

Server C:

Hostname: **c**.mydomain.com
Name Server 1: **ns5**.mydomain.com
Name Server 2: **ns6**.mydomain.com

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Flagged as duplicate with http://serverfault.com/questions/157485/how-to-use-the-same-domain-for-multiple-server-dnses